# Node.js typescript ES6 module not foud

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, module

I have some code in node.js typescript with ES6 modules, but imported module can't be found.

When i run `npm start` i have this output with error message:

```
 npm start

> sh@1.0.0 start
> npm run build && node dist/index.js


> sh@1.0.0 build
> tsc

node:internal/errors:490
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'D:\sh\dist\routes\map' imported from D:\sh\dist\index.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:326:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:945:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v18.16.0
```

I don't know why this is happing. Have no error in visual studio code.

File structure: [file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQEf3.png).

index.ts contains:

```
//@ts-check
import express from "express";
import map from './routes/map';

const app = express();
const port = 8000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);

app.get("/", (_req: any, res: any) => {
  res.json({ message: "Hello World!" });
});

app.use("/map", map);

app.use((err: any, _req: any, res: any, _next: any) => {
    const statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
    console.error(err.message, err.stack);
    res.status(statusCode).json({ message: err.message });
    return;
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

export default app;
```

map.ts contains:

```
//@ts-check
import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', async (_req, res, next) => {
  try {
    res.json({message: "Hello Worlds!"});
  } catch (err: any) {
    console.error(err.message);
    next(err);
  }
});

export default router;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sh",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "npm run build && node dist/index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/node": "^20.1.4",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "es6",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "strict": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
  }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Ok i found a solution - need to add  parameter for start script `--es-module-specifier-resolution=node`. But this feature is experimental an produces warning. Is there any other option to solve it?